# How to highlight differences in pandas data frame after concatenating them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as below:

```
XYZ
Year Quantity Car     Colour
2001 1000     Swift   Red
2001 16       Wagonar White
2001 16       Wagonar Black
2001 200      Baleno  Silver
2001 20       Zen     White

ABC  
Year Quantity Car     Colour
2001 1000     Swift   Red
2001 16       Wagonar White
2001 200      Baleno  Silver
2001 44       Alto    Blue
```

and the output should look like this:

```
Year      Quantity Car             Colour
XYZ  ABC  XYZ  ABC XYZ     ABC     XYZ    ABC
2001 2001 1000 100 Swift   Swift   Red    Red
2001 2001 16   16  Wagonar Wagonar White  White
2001 2001 16       Wagonar         Black 
2001 2001 200  200 Baleno  Baleno  Silver Silver
2001 2001 20       Zen             White
2001 2001      44          Alto           Blue
```

I have tried this

```
df_all = pd.concat([df_temp, df_temp1], axis='columns', keys=['XYZ', 'ABC'])
print(df_all)
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df_temp.columns]
print(df_final)
def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other = data.xs('First', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other, level=0), attr,''),index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

 df_final.style.apply(highlight_diff, axis=None)
 print(df_final)
```

The differences between the data frames should be highlighted.

For Example in this case Cars: Wagonar Zen and Alto has to be highlighted because they are different in two data frames

I tried this way of concatenating them :

```
    YEAR Quantity  CAR    COLOR  car     color
0   2001    16    Wagonar white  Wagonar white
1   2001    16    Wagonar black  Wagonar white
2   2001    20    Zen     white  NaN     NaN
3   2001    44    NaN     NaN    Alto    blue
4   2001   200    Baleno  silver Baleno  silver
5   2001  1000    Swift   red    Swift   red
```

All CAPS Headings belong to company xyz and small headings belong to abc
How do we compare "CAR" column with "car" column and also "COLOR" column with "color" column and highlight the entire row where the values don't match.

I have tried:

```
def highlight_rows(s):        
if not (s['CAR'] == s['car'] and s['COLOR'] == s['color']):
    return 'background-color: green'

df_final.style.apply(highlight_rows, axis = None)
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with duplicated pair `Year` and `Quantity`, so possible solution is create unique `MultiIndex` with counter before `concat`:

```
df_temp.index = df_temp.groupby(['Year','Quantity']).cumcount()
df_temp1.index = df_temp1.groupby(['Year','Quantity']).cumcount()

df_all = (pd.concat([df_temp.set_index(['Year','Quantity'], append=True), 
                     df_temp1.set_index(['Year','Quantity'], append=True)], 
                     axis='columns', 
                     keys=['XYZ', 'ABC']))
print(df_all)
                     XYZ              ABC        
                     Car  Colour      Car  Colour
  Year Quantity                                  
0 2001 16        Wagonar   White  Wagonar   White
       20            Zen   White      NaN     NaN
       44            NaN     NaN     Alto    Blue
       200        Baleno  Silver   Baleno  Silver
       1000        Swift     Red    Swift     Red
1 2001 16        Wagonar   Black      NaN     NaN
```

Then convert `index` to `DataFrame` and `concat` again for `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df_all.index.to_frame().drop(0, axis=1)
df1 = pd.concat([df, df], axis=1, keys=('XYZ','ABC'))
print (df1)
                  XYZ            ABC         
                 Year Quantity  Year Quantity
  Year Quantity                              
0 2001 16        2001       16  2001       16
       20        2001       20  2001       20
       44        2001       44  2001       44
       200       2001      200  2001      200
       1000      2001     1000  2001     1000
1 2001 16        2001       16  2001       16

df_final = df_all.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True).swaplevel(axis='columns')[df_temp.columns]
print(df_final)
   Year       Quantity            Car           Colour        
    XYZ   ABC      XYZ   ABC      XYZ      ABC     XYZ     ABC
0  2001  2001       16    16  Wagonar  Wagonar   White   White
1  2001  2001       20    20      Zen      NaN   White     NaN
2  2001  2001       44    44      NaN     Alto     NaN    Blue
3  2001  2001      200   200   Baleno   Baleno  Silver  Silver
4  2001  2001     1000  1000    Swift    Swift     Red     Red
5  2001  2001       16    16  Wagonar      NaN   Black     NaN
```

Last add new mask and combine by bitwise or - `|`:

```
def highlight_diff(data, color='yellow'):
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    other1 = data.xs('XYZ', axis='columns', level=-1)
    other2 = data.xs('ABC', axis='columns', level=-1)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(data.ne(other1, level=0) | 
                                 data.ne(other2, level=0), attr,''),
                        index=data.index, columns=data.columns)
```

---

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({('Year', 'XYZ'): {0: 2001, 1: 2001, 2: 2001, 3: 2001, 4: 2001, 5: 2001}, ('Year', 'ABC'): {0: 2001, 1: 2001, 2: 2001, 3: 2001, 4: 2001, 5: 2001}, ('Quantity', 'XYZ'): {0: 16, 1: 20, 2: 44, 3: 200, 4: 1000, 5: 16}, ('Quantity', 'ABC'): {0: 16, 1: 20, 2: 44, 3: 200, 4: 1000, 5: 16}, ('Car', 'XYZ'): {0: 'Wagonar', 1: 'Zen', 2: np.nan, 3: 'Baleno', 4: 'Swift', 5: 'Wagonar'}, ('Car', 'ABC'): {0: 'Wagonar', 1: np.nan, 2: 'Alto', 3: 'Baleno', 4: 'Swift', 5: np.nan}, ('Colour', 'XYZ'): {0: 'White', 1: 'White', 2: np.nan, 3: 'Silver', 4: 'Red', 5: 'Black'}, ('Colour', 'ABC'): {0: 'White', 1: np.nan, 2: 'Blue', 3: 'Silver', 4: 'Red', 5: np.nan}})
```

---

[image: pic]

Comment: Still doesn't work and im not doing the merging correctly with my code and I need help

Comment: @Miffy - More complicated like seems, but now working. Please check it.

Comment: Both the wagonar should be together and entire car should be highlighted not just the white colour

Comment: @Miffy - `entire car should be highlighted not just the white colour` - Can you explain more?

Comment: so first we check for quantities manufactured my both companies xyz and abc. Here company xyz manufactures 16 white and 16 black wagonars whereas company abc manufactures only 16 white wagonars. So there is a difference in manufacturing of wagonar car and hence two rows where the car name is wagonar needs to be highlighted

Comment: @Miffy - So in my answer need by yellow rows number 1,2,5 correct ordered?

Comment: @Miffy - Also there is main problem in concat different number of rows - so not easy compare between them. My soluion working compare by first 2 columns (are fixed). But not sure if need it...

Comment: rows 0,1,2 and 5 needs to be highlighted and we need not compare year columns. We need to just compare from Quantity columns